# Auth0 nickname property works after reload in angular 2

Tags: angular, auth0

I want to display the name of the user when he logs in using auth0. When the user signs in the name is not shown in the nav bar. But when we reload the page the name appears.

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SignupService} from './services/signup.service';
import {Auth} from './services/auth.service';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assets/css/navbar.css'],
  providers: [SignupService],
  })
 export class AppComponent  {
  profile : any;
  constructor(private auth: Auth){

  this.profile=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();


  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you only gather the value on startup.

You should either:

- re-get the value every few seconds:
  `setTimeout(() => localStorage.getItem('profile'), 1000)`
- inject an Auth [service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) to your desired controller that uses shared variables. So you can update the logged in values displayed in the template.
- use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html), to call a function that modifies the appropriate log in controller.

Comment: Where should I add setTimeout() function?

Comment: @KarthikSKumar considering that `this.profile` is the variable that visually displays the user being logged in or not, you should encapsulate that whole line into a `setTimeout` function.
`setTimeout(() => { this.profile=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')); }, 100);`

Comment: @KarthikSKumar make sure that `this.profile` is **the** variable that you are displaying afterwards on the controller's template (i.e. `{{profile.username}}`). Otherwise you will need to reload some other variable.

Comment: I used that variable itself but till not working. I think the navbar loads before the variable gets initialized and it leads to some error